# Add time stamp to photo upload

Tags: ios, image, timestamp

I am uploading a photo from my iOS app to my server. Currently I am hard coding the name of the photo that I am uploading but this causes all subsequent photos to be overwritten (naturally). To combat this I would like to create a new name for the image, preferably by adding a header (which I define in a separate text field) as well as a timestamp of when it was uploaded. My attempts at this code are as follows, however they do not work :P ...

```
NSString * timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat,[[NSDate date], timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
        var header:NSString = txtHeader.text
        let filename = (header)&&(timestamp)&&"image.jpg"
        let mimetype = "image/jpg"
```

Comment: Why you mix Swift and Objective C code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like

```
var currentTimeStamp = String(Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970))
```

can also add

```
extension Double {
    func format(f: String) -> String {
        return NSString(format: "%\(f)f", self) as String
    }

    func toString() -> String {
        return String(format: "%.1f",self)
    }

    func toInt() -> Int{
        var temp:Int64 = Int64(self)
        return Int(temp)
    }
}

var currentTimeStamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970.toString()
```

edit: filename

```
let filename = "\(header)_\(currentTimeStamp)_img.jpg"
```

Comment: thank you - how would the final "filename" statement look then?